# Rank() function. Extract Top 3 count from query, belonged to mother query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Mother Table A like this below.

```
Animal Category                   Count        
      Cat                           15        
      Dog                           13        
    Raptile                         20
```

I also have a Child Table B like this below.

```
Animal colour                     Count        
  Grey Cat                          6        
  Red Cat                           3        
  White Cat                         4
  Black Cat                         2
  Yellow Dog                        7
  Black Dog                         1
  Red Dog                           2
  Grey Dog                          3
  Red Reptile                       5
  Blue Reptile                      10
  Green Reptile                     2
  Yellow Reptile                    3
```

But I want to have a table that shows count of only Top3 animal colours from child table B by each animal category from mother table A in one table.

So, my result should be like below.

```
Animal colour                     Count        
  Grey Cat                          6        
  White Cat                         4        
  Red Cat                           3

  Yellow Dog                        7
  Grey Dog                          3
  Red Dog                           2

  Blue Reptile                      10
  Red Reptile                       5
  Yellow Reptile                    3
```

Is it possible to use rank(), count(*) over with subquery to retrieve data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
select * from (
     select rank() over (partition by categorie order by "Count" DESC) rank,* from (
              select (string_to_array("Animal colour",' '))[2] categorie,* from b
          ) a) b where rank<=3 order by categorie,rank
```

but your field "Animal colour" containing the categorie and the colour is a very bad idea.